# Save the result of a SQL query into a variable in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am trying to assign the result of the query into the variable. I have one query (lets call it "Query1") that will check various criteria. I tried it as follows.

```
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim Variable1 As String

   strQry = "Query1"
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

 Variable1 = ????? 
   rst.Close
   Set rst = Nothing
```

I need help to complete the above code so that my variable will get the value returned by the query. Please note that my Query1 will either return a Null value or a single record.

Comment: what are the column names in query1?, also you appear to have a mismatch with `strSQL` and `strQry`

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why you need a recordset for this.  You could use `DLookup` to fetch the value returned by `Query1`.

```vb
Dim Variable1 As Variant
Variable1 = DLookup("[column name here]", "Query1")
```

I used `Variant` for `Variable1` so that it can accept Null.  If you wish to keep it as `String`, you can use `Nz()` as Andre demonstrated to transform Null to a string.

Answer (score 2):

If your query returns only a single column, and only zero or one records, you can use `rst(0)` to get the first field (the Fields collection is zero-based).

```
If rst.EOF Then
    ' covers "no records returned"
    Variable1 = ""
Else
    ' Nz() covers "NULL returned"
    Variable1 = Nz(rst(0), "")
End If
```

But using the field name from the query is better readable.

```
Variable1 = Nz(rst!myField, "")
```

You may also want to look into the `DLookup()` function, which is designed to return a single value.